# Winter14 describeQuickActions

Tags: apex, pre-release, winter14

playing around with Winter14 and struggling with QuickActions describeQuickActions

http://bit.ly/16FlwNA

the Preview Docu for DescribeQuickActionResult mentions the describeQuickActions to get this type, yet I cant find any more details on the method.

Has anyone input on this?

Answer (score 2):

The prerelease Apex Code guide has a few topics, including a page on DescribeQuickActionsResult instance methods for retrieving information about the action such as type of action, size, name of canvas app or visualforce page.

I attempted to get a working link, but since this is sitting in early pre-release right now, none of the document locations that I was able to find created reliable links.

So, here's how to find it.

1. Go to the [HTML version of the pre-release guide](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcodepre/index.htm).
2. Click on **Search**.
3. Enter "describeQuickActions" in the search box and click **Search**.
4. I found one result here. Select that. And on that page is the link for the DescribeQuickActionsResult instance methods.

**This answer will need to be updated post-GA**

Comment: thanks for the feedback. but how do I actually get an instance of a DescribeQuickActionsResult, its returned by the 'describeQuickActions' method, yet I cant feed any details on the describeQuickActions method at all

Comment: I see what you mean. Some fiddling around with the Dev Console didn't yield anything. Just copied SalesforceDocs on the tweet for this.

Answer (score 1):

Got feedback from @salesforcedocs

*describeQuickActions takes as its argument a list of action names & returns a list of QuickAction.DescribeQuickActionResult objects.*

```
QuickAction.DescribeQuickActionResult[] result = QuickAction.describeQuickActions(new String[]{Schema.Account.QuickAction.NewContact})
```

Answer (score 1):

This is an old question, but for the sake of any who stumble across it later, here's the documentation for the [QuickAction class](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_class_system_quickaction.htm).

To get a list of available quick actions on an object or the Chatter tab:

```
// Called for Account entity.
List<QuickAction.DescribeAvailableQuickActionResult> result1 = 
    QuickAction.DescribeAvailableQuickActions('Account');  

// Called at global level, not entity level.
List<QuickAction.DescribeAvailableQuickActionResult> result2 = 
    QuickAction.DescribeAvailableQuickActions('Global');
```

To get details on a specific action, see the documentation for [DescribeQuickActionResult](https://www.salesforce.com/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_calls_describequickactionresult.htm).

An example: get all the rows in the default global "New Lead" action:

```
QuickAction.DescribeQuickActionResult[] results = QuickAction.describeQuickActions(new String[]{ QuickAction.NewLead });
for (QuickAction.DescribeQuickActionResult res : results) {
    for (QuickAction.DescribeLayoutRow row : res.getLayout().getLayoutRows()) {
        // Do something with each row
    }
}
```